# Spring-HIbernate: entity id before the entity is persisted

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

How do I retrieve the id of the newly persisted Entity before the transaction is complete when using @Transactional annotation.?

Lets say I have a User table with it's id being generated by database sequence..

User.java

```
 @Entity
 public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="USERSEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="USERSEQ", sequenceName = "USERSEQ")
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME", nullable=false)
    private String lastName;
  }
```

I want to do something like this in the service class.. persist the user object, then get the id of that entity, add it to the audit object and then persist it.. But the issue is that user object isn't really persisted so the id added to the audit object isn't the real id of the new user record.

UserService.java

```
  @Transactional
  public void addUser(User newUser, UserAudit userAudit ){
         newUser = userDao.addUser(newUser);
         userAudit.setUserId(newUser.getId());
         userAuditDao.addUserAudit(userAudit);
  }
```

I tried to flush the session before returning the user object from the dao layer but it doesnt seem to work...

UserDao.java

```
  public User addUser(User user){
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     user = (User) session.merge(user);
      session.flush();
    return user;
  }
```

So what do I need here to retrieve id in the service layer before the transaction is complete? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want session.save(user) or session.saveOrUpdate(user).  According to the JavaDocs:

> merge(String entityName, Object object) - Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier.
>
> save(Object object) - Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier

I think merge requires an already-persisted entity, which is why merge()/flush() isn't giving you one.  Save()/flush() should, however.

Comment: but all those two methods dont return anything. How do I get the Id of the freshly persisted entity if I use anyone of those two methods?

Comment: save() also doesn't seem to work in my case because the id is generated by database sequence. And that sequence wont be generated until the transaction is actually committed

Comment: You don't need to commit a transaction to get a generated sequence identifier from the database.  (If you're in the middle of a transaction block and issue a save(), the database sequence generates the identifier.  If you commit, the INSERT is committed along with the changes to the sequence.  If you roll back, the INSERT is rolled back along with changes to the sequence.)

Comment: save()/merge() doesn't need to return anything.  save() turns your newly-created transient object into a managed object - it inserts the generated ID into your object for you.  Also, I'm not so sure you need flush() - when I use Hibernate as a JPA 2 provider and I make a call to EntityManager.persist() (which ends up calling session.persist() or session.save()) I can read back the generated ID immediately, without having to call flush().

Comment: I think the trick is in the "if you commit, the INSERT is committed along with the changes to the sequence" part.. when I call session.save(), Hibernate is adding some fake value to the id attribute since it doesn't  know the actual nextval in sequence until the transaction is committed.. and that fake value is added to useraudit object since because the transaction isnt committed yet

Comment: Maybe with straight Hibernate that's how it works.  However, given that I've observed JPA 2 w/ Hibernate giving me the generated ID immediately after calling EntityManager.persist(), that also means there is a way to make straight Hibernate perform exactly the same way - since JPA 2 just ends up making sequences of Hibernate calls.

This is going to sound strange, but have you actually *tried* using save(), save()/flush(), persist(), persist()/flush() and displaying the value of your ID field?  I would find it odd for EntityManager.persist() to do much more than call Session.persist().

Comment: Yes BobG.. I tried all save(flush()), persist(flush()).. nothing works.. I looked at the SQL created by hibernate and it is something like.. `insert into  User(FIRSTNAME, ID) values('blah',12345)` and `insert into UserAudit(FIRSTNAME, ID, USERID) values('blah',54652,12345)` but the thing is, once the transaction is committed, the values in the database are User->('blah',100), UserAudit->('blah',200,12345)... it doesn't matter even if i use flush().. it is still not getting the value from sequence..

Comment: This URL had some interesting information: http://www.coderanch.com/t/215521/ORM/java/Hibernate-ID-not-set-upon

Try changing from `int id` to `Integer id` and using persist(), then check the ID value.  (Incidentally, the Hibernate javadocs indicate that save() should return the generated sequence value.)

Comment: I have long Id - changed it to Long id but still no luck with the persist method.. i can see clearly no call to the database is made till the @transactional method is complete even if I use flush :(

Comment: I think I found the issue Bob.. I had to change strategy to GenerationType.Auto from Sequence which is weird because Auto should default to Sequence for Oracle right? our database uses trigger to get the next sequence value.. does it have something to do with it? Thank for all your help Bob..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4706/discussion-between-bobg-and-rrkwells)